# saving image type with its original file type

Tags: vb.net

i needed to save an image into my vb proj. I am using a process to save an image to a local folder using it's file name. However, to do it my code has to convert the format to .jpg. What i needed was to save the file with it's original type, since my project will be receiving different image type and maps as well as .pdf in it. is there any way i could change the `imageformat.jpeg`to something else that will save the image to it's original format?

this is the code i am using to save the image.
to create directory

```vb
 If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text & "/")) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text & "/")
            End If
```

to save the image

```
Upload.PictureBox1.Image.Save("d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text & "/" + Upload.TextBox1.Text, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

i am using MSVisual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

thanks

Comment: how did you acquire the original format image/file? and what is that format?

Comment: If you are wanting to retain the original file format, why not just copy all incoming files into an "original" folder, copy them to a different folder, and only ever mess with the copies?

Comment: @plutonix my project filters the file types when searching for the files..but when it comes to saving them the proj converts them to .jpeg...example is .png or .gif and others, they are all being converted to .jpeg. i want to retain there file types

Comment: @ghost I don't think I get where your getting at..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to do this would be that when you load the image into the picturebox you can save the original extension in the tag:

```
Dim sFilename As String = "c:\test.png" ' However you are populating your picturebox, you can change this variable to the full path of the file

Upload.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(sFilename)
Upload.PictureBox1.Tag = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sFilename).ToLower    ' Saves the extension to the picturebox in the tag field so that we can evaluate it later
```

Then when you need to save the image back to a file, you can write it back in the same image format as before:

```
' Figure out what the original image format was

Dim oImageFormat As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat

Select Case PictureBox1.Tag.ToString
    Case ".jpeg", ".jpg"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
    Case ".png"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png
    Case ".bmp"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp
    Case ".gif"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif
    Case ".tif", ".tiff"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff
    Case ".ico", ".icon"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon
    Case ".emf"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf
    Case ".exif"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Exif
    Case ".wmf"
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf
    Case Else
        ' This should never happen but just in case the extension cannot be found we default to jpeg output
        oImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
End Select

' Save the image with in the proper format again

Upload.PictureBox1.Image.Save("d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text & "/" & Upload.TextBox1.Text & PictureBox1.Tag.ToString, oImageFormat)
```

**Notes regarding pdf:** The Picturebox control does not support pdf files and therefore you will not be able to load pdfs this way. I suggest you convert the pdf to an image file that is supported and then load it into your app after conversion. If this isn't feasible you will have to choose a different control to handle your pdfs such as the WebBrowser control.

Comment: it worked perfectly..thanks, also..i added a code for saving other attachments.. `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Upload.Label14.Text, "d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text & "/" + Upload.Label16.Text, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing) ` and i have a delete command that would delete the folder..the command for deletion was working before, but since i added the copyfile coommand, it says unreachable path..

Comment: this is the code for delete.. `If (System.IO.Directory.Exists("d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text & "/")) Then

                        Dim path As String = "d:/Site Images/" & Label33.Text
                        System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, True)
                        'My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path)
                    End If`

Comment: Unfortunately it's very difficult to debug your code in a comment. I would recommend you post another question and I or someone else can help you further. A couple of tips: 1) You can use the built in function `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to fit paths together properly without having to worry about needing to put the slashes in all the time 2) If you are reusing a path multiple times you should put it into its own variable to ensure that you aren't recreating it improperly as may be the case with your delete code. 3) Don't be afraid to use the debugger to find your own mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file extension to see what the original image file format is. When you save the file, you can specify the original format in the Picturebox Image.Save function, such as `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png`.

If that format is not supported by .net (see link below), you can use a third-party library such as freeImage.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx